Pass multi line env variable to docker-compose from github actions
My DATABASE_CA env variable saved in my github secrets is a multi line file representing the certificate of my database. The ca file is a multi line file that I need to export to my vps to be used in my docker-compose.
name: Deploy prod stack to DigitalOcean

on:
  create:
    branches:
      - release
  push:
    branches:
      - release
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - release

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checking out the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Copy docker-compose.prod.yml over to the server
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@v0.1.7
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
          passphrase: ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}
          source: "docker-compose.prod.yml"
          target: /home/${{ secrets.USERNAME }}

      - name: Run the docker-compose.prod.yml stack
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.6
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
          passphrase: ${{ secrets.PASSPHRASE }}
          script: |
            echo ${{ secrets.CR_PAT }} | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin
            export DATABASE_HOST=${{ secrets.DATABASE_HOST }}
            export DATABASE_PORT=${{ secrets.DATABASE_PORT }}
            export DATABASE_NAME=${{ secrets.DATABASE_NAME }}
            export DATABASE_USERNAME=${{ secrets.DATABASE_USERNAME }}
            export DATABASE_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD }}
            export DATABASE_CA=${{ secrets.DATABASE_CA }}
            export APP_KEYS=${{ secrets.APP_KEYS }}
            export API_TOKEN_SALT=${{ secrets.API_TOKEN_SALT }}
            export ADMIN_JWT_SECRET=${{ secrets.ADMIN_JWT_SECRET }}
            export JWT_SECRET=${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET }}
            export R2_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ secrets.R2_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
            export R2_ACCESS_SECRET=${{ secrets.R2_ACCESS_SECRET }}
            export R2_ENDPOINT=${{ secrets.R2_ENDPOINT }}
            export R2_BUCKET=${{ secrets.R2_BUCKET }}
            export R2_PUBLIC_ACCESS_URL=${{ secrets.R2_PUBLIC_ACCESS_URL }}
            export APP_URL=${{ secrets.APP_URL }}
            docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down
            docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml pull
            docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d


Have you tried putting it in double quotes. export APP_KEYS="${{ secrets.APP_KEYS }}"

Yes I actually did try it, I get err: bash: -c: line 31: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
